# How to get a button to be clicked without human interaction?

Tags: java, android

I have a functionality for tic tac toe where basically when the player clicks a button to place their X, the computer's O is placed at the same time within the first empty button available.

However what I prefer is **after** the player places an X, the computer places their O on the first empty button available, not the same time. Is there a way to get the computer to click on an empty button by itself?

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (playerOneMove) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
            ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
            computerMove();
        }
}

    private boolean computerMove() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                if (field[i][j] == "") {
                    buttons[i][j].setText("O");
                    buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Whole code snippet:

```
public class MainActivityPlayer1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean playerOneMove = true;

    private int turnsCount;

    private int playerOnePoints;
    private int playerTwoPoints;

    private TextView textViewPlayerOne;
    private TextView textViewPlayerTwo;
    private TextView textViewPlayerOneTurn;
    private TextView textViewPlayerTwoTurn;

    int playerX = Color.parseColor("#e8e5e5");
    int playerO = Color.parseColor("#737374");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_player2);

        textViewPlayerOne = findViewById(R.id.textView_player1);
        textViewPlayerTwo = findViewById(R.id.textView_player2);
        textViewPlayerOneTurn = findViewById(R.id.textView_player1Turn);
        textViewPlayerTwoTurn = findViewById(R.id.textView_player2Turn);


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    String btnState = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(buttonID).toString();
                    if (btnState.equals("X")) {
                        buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerX);
                    } else {
                        buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
            }
        });

        Button buttonExit = findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                backToMainActivity();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (playerOneMove) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
            ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
            playerOneMove = false;
            computerMove();
        }

        turnsCount++;

        if (checkGameIsWon()) {
            if (playerOneMove) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (turnsCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
            switchPlayerTurn();
        }
    }

    private boolean computerMove() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                if (field[i][j] == "") {
                    buttons[i][j].setText("O");
                    buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void player1Wins() {
        playerOnePoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void player2Wins() {
        playerTwoPoints++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Computer wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    private void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayerOne.setText("Player 1:  " + playerOnePoints + " ");
        textViewPlayerTwo.setText("Computer: " + playerTwoPoints + " ");
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }

        turnsCount = 0;
        switchPlayerTurn();
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        playerOnePoints = 0;
        playerTwoPoints = 0;
        turnsCount = 0;
        playerOneMove = true;
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("turnsCount", turnsCount);
        outState.putInt("playerOnePoints", playerOnePoints);
        outState.putInt("playerTwoPoints", playerTwoPoints);
        outState.putBoolean("playerOneMove", playerOneMove);
        switchPlayerTurn();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                outState.putCharSequence(buttonID, btn.getText());

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        turnsCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("turnsCount");
        playerOnePoints = savedInstanceState.getInt("playerOnePoints");
        playerTwoPoints = savedInstanceState.getInt("playerTwoPoints");
        playerOneMove = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("playerOneMove");
        switchPlayerTurn();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                Button btn = buttons[i][j];
                savedInstanceState.putCharSequence(buttonID, btn.getText());

            }
        }

    }

    private void switchPlayerTurn(){
        if (playerOneMove){
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            textViewPlayerOneTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textViewPlayerTwoTurn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void backToMainActivity(){
        Intent intentMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentMainActivity);
    }

}
```

Comment: Right now your code is doing what you want, the player clicks the button, the button text changes and then you call computerMove(). Do you want a delay before the computer makes a move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
button.performClick();
```

**UPDATE** after going through op's code:

Your code was perfectly fine but had one small bug. In your `computerMove()` function, you had compared strings using `==` which is prone to cause problems in Java. I replaced it with `String.equals(String)` and played a game. Works fine.

```
private boolean computerMove() {
    String[][] field = new String[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("O");
                buttons[i][j].setTextColor(playerO);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you direct me on how to implement this please in the code, as I seem to not get it right?

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  Performing a click makes a move for X (the person), but you want a move for O (the computer).  Also, if you do this in the `click` method, you'll get an endless loop.

Comment: On the button that you want to click programmatically, call the performClick() method. It is used to simulate a click. Keep in mind that it WILL trigger your onCLickListener on that button.

@dawoodibnKareem No it won't go into an endless loop. "if" condition will fail after no blank slot is left.

Comment: Right.  So you'll get 9 Xs filled in as soon as the human clicks once.  Still not what OP had in mind.

Comment: Even then, the op has a flag to check if it was a player move or computer move.

Comment: @ShashwatRazdan Just place which line I should put it in the code snippet so I can see it and I will give it a test. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Can you tell me how are you modifying the playerOneMove boolean?

Comment: Sure, let me post the whole snippet so you can see how it works.

Comment: Updated my answer. If it works for you, please accept it.

Comment: Ok well we can do it this way but there are two problems that occur. Can I send a link to another question and put it here as you have the code anyway? It's been something I have been challenging for the last 45 mins

Comment: The glitch is basically if I go first and computer second. I will put 2 X and it puts 2 O, when I put my X to complete 3 in a row then the computer places its O and wins when it should be me who run. That's the glitch

Comment: Check for winning situation before computer's move. Maybe check again after computer's move.